# How to put color behind axes in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make some plots in python 3 for a data science project, and I'm having an issue where there is no color behind the text on my axes when I save it. Here's my code with an example plot:

```
plt.plot(play_num_2019[g], home_prob_2019[g], color = getColor(home_teams_2019[g]))
plt.plot(play_num_2019[g], away_prob_2019[g], color = getColor(away_teams_2019[g]))
plt.xlabel("Play Number")
plt.ylabel("Win Probability")
plt.legend([home_teams_2019[g], away_teams_2019[g]])
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: If either of the posted answers answered your question be sure to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question is marked as such for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlibrc-sample) contains the plot parameters for `matplotlib`, stored in *matplotlibrc* file. You can change the parameters either directly in the matplotlibrc file (as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file)), or in your code, just before plotting. Here is an example to change the figure background color as you requested:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.plot as plt

plt.plot(play_num_2019[g], home_prob_2019[g], color = getColor(home_teams_2019[g]))
plt.plot(play_num_2019[g], away_prob_2019[g], color = getColor(away_teams_2019[g]))
plt.xlabel("Play Number")
plt.ylabel("Win Probability")
mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'r' # <--- here is the line for changing the background to red
plt.legend([home_teams_2019[g], away_teams_2019[g]])
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
```

If you want to change it only when the figure is saved, change the following parameter instead.

```
mpl.rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] = 'r'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the facecolor for a figure you can either use `matplotlib.rcParams` to set the a facecolcolor globally - for all figures - or for a single figure you can specify the facecolor in calling `plt.savefig()`. If you want to set the facecolor using `fig.patch.set_facecolor()` you can then simply use `fig.get_facecolor()` in `savefig()`. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.plot(x, np.cos(np.sin(x)))
fig.patch.set_facecolor((0.68, 0.78, 0.91))

plt.savefig('/path/to/output.png', facecolor = fig.get_facecolor())
```

Output

[image]

If you want this color applied behind the plot area as well then you must pass `transparent=True` in `plt.savefig()` which will give you

[image]

Or - as I prefer - you can set the alpha of the axes patch like so

```py
plt.gca().patch.set_alpha(0.7)
```

or the like. This will produce

[image]

---

**Note**   -    Setting the facecolor to `'xkcd:white'` won't have any effect because the corresponding RGB values are `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` - identical to the default facecolor.